# Gradle sync failed, implementations

Tags: java, gradle

Не понимаю в чём проблема. "Gradle sync failed".

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.6'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

---

Содержимое другого Gradle.

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Мы тоже не понимаем. Причина failed обычно указана. Читайте текст ошибки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы неправильную версию библиотеки используете. Вот список актуальных версий:

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

В данном случае попробуйте подключить

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
```

Comment: Не помогло. После добавления данной строки пишет следующее: Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.1.3. Required by: project :app.

Comment: Пробовал убрать строчку "apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'" в самом конце, то приложение начало запускаться, но крашится.

Comment: Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 16.0.7.

Comment: @Danil, покажите содержимое второго `gradle` файла.

Comment: Добавил его содержимое в мой вопрос.

Comment: @Danil, обновите и второй `gradle` файл. Судя по ошибке вы что-то не то скопировали откуда-то. Проверьте номер версии у себя и в моём ответе.

Comment: Gradle синхронизируется успешно, но теперь присутствуют ошибки в Run Build при скачивании чего-то с "dl.google.com...".